# VisualSVN - merging revisions into one

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge, restore, visualsvn

We have some server with VisualSVN free service. Because we want to make some space on it, I determined to merge some old projects' revisions. They are not used anymore (the old revs.).

To test this I created a local visualsvn server on Win7 machine.
I created a repository project named "test", and some python tool that call the svnadmin as needed.

I commited a text file with 5 of revisions.

Dump, I save this project:

```
E:\Repository_Saver>dump.py
c:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe dump e:\Repositories\te
st -r 5 >E:\Repository_Saver\test.dump
* Dumped revision 5.
```

Restore to this project (without delete it). I got error:

```
E:\Repository_Saver>restore.py
c:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe load e:\Repositories\te
st --ignore-uuid
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 5
     * adding path : trunk ...svnadmin: File already exists: filesystem 'e:\Repo
sitories\test\db', transaction '5-6', path 'trunk'
```

I created a new project dir with VisualSVN, and I tried to restore the dump:

```
E:\Repository_Saver>restore.py
c:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe load e:\Repositories\te
st2vs --ignore-uuid
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 5
     * adding path : trunk ...svnadmin: File already exists: filesystem 'e:\Repo
sitories\test2vs\db', transaction '1-1', path 'trunk'
```

I tried to restore into a nonexistent project dir:

```
E:\Repository_Saver>restore.py
c:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe load e:\Repositories\te
st2notexists --ignore-uuid
svnadmin: Can't open file 'e:\Repositories\test2notexists\format': A rendszer ne
m találja a megadott elérési utat.
(The system not found the path)
```

I created a test2 project with svnadmin only. Try to restore here:

```
E:\Repository_Saver>restore.py
c:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe load --ignore-uuid e:\R
epositories\test2
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 5
     * adding path : trunk ... done.
     * adding path : trunk/akarmi.txt ...svnadmin: Checksum mismatch, file '/tru
nk/akarmi.txt':
   expected:  c8f86f8733e4cb120d475cfd118bd93a
     actual:  94bed0edc96af1cc6f87cb19ec81ef9e
```

With forcing:

```
E:\Repository_Saver>restore.py
c:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe load --force-uuid e:\Re
positories\test2
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 5
     * adding path : trunk ... done.
     * adding path : trunk/akarmi.txt ...svnadmin: Checksum mismatch, file '/tru
nk/akarmi.txt':
   expected:  c8f86f8733e4cb120d475cfd118bd93a
     actual:  94bed0edc96af1cc6f87cb19ec81ef9e
```

So that is the list of my tryings. I cannot restore the dump to anywhere.
But this needed to I can merge revisions.

What I do wrong? What I need to do?

This local machine is Win7/x64, with VisualSVN Free.
But I tried with these operations also in Win2k3, and I also got these errors.

THanks for every idea, help, link, trying...

dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. I simplified the code of the create/dump/load to this:

-- create --

```
"c:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe" create %1
```

-- dump --

```
"c:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe" dump -r%2 %1 >%1.dump
```

-- load --

```
"c:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe" load %1 <%2.dump
```

usage:

The new, merged repos.

```
create project_merged
```

Dump with last rev. what is 39

```
dump project_original 39
```

Load the dump file into new repos.

```
load project_merged project_original
```

Important: the dumped file must be unopened before load!
I everytime made this mistake that I opened it (to see the content).

The GUI repository "creating" is not working with load. VisualSVN is make some plus files... :-(

Thanks:
   dd